# When installing Guzzle via Composer where do I place the require vendor/autoload.php

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Following the install instructions for composer here:
https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Next, run the Composer command to install the latest stable version of Guzzle:

composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle

This is straight forward and works.

After installing, you need to require Composer's autoloader:

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

I'm not sure about where to require the autoloader. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Guzzle appears to work without this step but I'm looking for some clarification if this is needed and if so where to add the require.

I'm using Laravel 4.2 btw.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Laravel 4.2 you don't need to do anything.

Laravel 4.2 automatically includes composer autoloader for you so you don't have to.  If you were writing stand alone scripts, or your own framework, you'd need to require the autoloader yourself.

(Also, if the autoloader wasn't required, you wouldn't be able to instantiate Guzzle classes with manually requiring or including the files)

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091827/how-can-i-require-composer-autoloader-in-the-laravel