# How can I require composer autoloader in the laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle, laravel-5.6, autoloader

I want to install guzzle https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

I read the reference, but I'm confused this section :

[image]

From that tutorial, asking for require composer autoloader. So seems needed to add `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`
Where I add the script?

I using laravel 5.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to do anything if you are going to install guzzle in Laravel.
The example above is for core php actually. Laravel will automatically do it for you.

Just run `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` in your terminal. (of course in the directory where your laravel project actually is.) 
And add `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` at the top of the file you will be calling guzzle from.